# $\lim_{h\to 0}\int \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\,\mathrm{d}x = f(b)-f(a)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:[a,b]\to  R$ be integrable and continuous on $(a,b)$. Prove that:
>
> $$\lim_{h\to 0} \int_a^b\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \,\mathrm{d}x = f(b)-f(a).$$

What I've tried so far: make a change of variables, which didn't help. I also thought of using the intermediate value theorem inside the integral, but the function being differentiable is not specified.

Any help, tips? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A change of variable (for one part of the integral) is a good start. What exactly did you try, and how did it not help?

Comment: @MartinR i have tried something like $u = x+h$.

Comment: That's fine. Edit your question and show what you got.

Comment: @MartinR, I will get:

$\int_{a+h}^{b+h}\frac{f(u)-f(u-h)}{u-x}du$. How to proceed? I'm sorry, i can't see clearly.

Comment: Can the LHS be well-defined?  We know nothing about $f$ on $[b, b+h]$.  $f$ can be so discontinuous (say, $f$ is the indicator function of $\Bbb{Q}$ outside $[a,b]$.) that $\int_a^b f(x+h) dx = \int_{a+h}^{b+h} f(x) dx$ is *not* even defined (in Riemann sense).

Comment: Consider $f(x)=1$ when $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x\leq 0$. Surely $f(x)$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ and consinuous on $(0,1)$. Moreover for any $h>0$, we have $\int_0^1\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}dx=0$, thus $\lim_{h\to 0^+}\int_0^1\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}dx=0$. However $f(1)-f(0)=1-0=1$. Thus what you are trying to prove is false.

Comment: What is $f(x + h)$ when $x + h > b$?

Comment: @FrankLu you should make an answer out of your comment.

Comment: @user159517 Not at this moment I think. Maybe the OP made certain mistakes/typos or had more details to be added. I'll see if there're any edits.

Comment: Thank you guys for your considerations. I posted the questions as stated by my professor, but as you have pointed out he was not very careful.

Comment: It's best to mention that $f$ is defined on an open interval $I$ and $[a, b] \subset I$ such that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ and continuous on points $a, b$. The result holds under these conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{align}\\
 \int_a^b\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} dx
&=\frac1{h}\left( \int_a^b f(x+h)dx-\int_a^bf(x)dx\right)\\
&=\frac1{h}\left( \int_{a+h}^{b+h} f(x)dx-\int_a^bf(x)dx\right)\\
&=\frac1{h}\left( \int_{a+h}^{b} f(x)dx+\int_{b}^{b+h} f(x)dx-\left(\int_{a}^{a+h}f(x)dx+\int_{a+h}^bf(x)dx\right)\right)\\
&=\frac1{h}\left( \int_{b}^{b+h} f(x)dx-\int_{a}^{a+h}f(x)dx\right)\\
&=\frac1{h}\int_{b}^{b+h} f(x)dx-\frac1{h}\int_{a}^{a+h}f(x)dx\\
&\underbrace{\longrightarrow}_{h \to 0} f(b)-f(a)
\qquad\text{if }f \text{ is continuous on }[a, b+h]\\
\end{align}
$

Comment: why does exactly $1/h \int_{b}^{b+h}f(x)dx$ goes to $f(b)$ as $h$ goes to $0$? Intuitively i can see it, as you are considering the small rectangle of area $hf(b)$ and dividing by $h$.

Comment: Because $f$ is continuous, it changes by a small amount from $b$ to $b+h$.

Comment: Hm, i could justify this step by setting $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt$ and then writing those above in a such way that it reminds the definition of derivative. Since $f$ is continuous, it will be $f(b)-f(a)$

Answer (score 0):

It is tacitly assumed that $f$ is integrable over a slightly larger interval. Let a small $h>0$ be given (the proof for $h<0$ is analogous). Then
$$\eqalign{\int_a^b\bigl(f(x+h)-f(x)\bigr)\>dx&=\int_{a+h}^{b+h} f(x)\>dx-\int_a^b f(x)\>dx\cr &=\int_b^{b+h}f(x)\>dx-\int_a^{a+h}f(x)\>dx\ ,\cr}$$
using elementary properties of the Riemann integral. Since $f$ is continuous the MVT  provides us with two points $\alpha\in[a,a+h]$, $\>\beta\in[b,b+h]$ such that
$$\int_a^b\bigl(f(x+h)-f(x)\bigr)\>dx=h\bigl(f(\beta)-f(\alpha)\bigr)\ .$$
It follows that
$$\lim_{h\to0+}{1\over h}\int_a^b\bigl(f(x+h)-f(x)\bigr)\>dx=f(b)-f(a)\ .$$