# Prove that this continuous function?

Tags: calculus

Let *f* be continuous on $\left [ a,b \right ]$ , and a$<$x$<$b.
Prove that:$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{a}^{x}\left ( f\left ( t+h \right )-f\left ( t \right ) \right )dt=f\left(x \right )-f\left(a\right)$$

I have tried Mean Value Theorm to solve it, but it didn't work. And I've been stuck on this for a while without any idea. Is it possible for someone to help me? Or give a hint.
Thanks!

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2759301/42969

Comment: @Shaun Sorry, I'll try to make the titles more informative next time. And thanks for your advice. They are very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Change of variables in $\int_a^x f(t+h)\; dt$.